# Filter columns in a DataFrame based on values in one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

I have a `DataFrame` of size 62,4. Column 1 is a filename string. Column 2 is composed of location data (fieldname sourcedep) and each cell has a shape of (4,). Column 3 is composed of other location data (fieldname chanloc) with each cell having shape (24,5), and finally column 4 (fieldname picktime) is composed of time data and each cell has shape (24,1).

```
    ,filename,sourcedep,chanloc,picktime
0,29378.dat,"count           63.000000
EASTING (x)      0.137875
NORTHING (y)    -1.084750
depth          -23.250000
Name: 0, dtype: float64","    count  channel  EASTING (x)  NORTHING (y)  depth (m)
0     125       49     0.146875      1.391000     -22.94
1     126       50     0.140115      1.384478     -22.44
2     127       51     0.129401      1.372682     -21.94
3     128       52     0.118641      1.360286     -21.44
4     129       53     0.108410      1.348083     -20.94
5     130       54     0.099063      1.336708     -20.44
6     131       55     0.090169      1.324554     -19.94
7     132       56     0.080361      1.310292     -19.44
8     133       57     0.071939      1.297892     -18.94
9     134       58     0.065468      1.288199     -18.44
10    135       59     0.059845      1.278037     -17.94
11    136       60     0.054432      1.266832     -17.44
12    137       61     0.050194      1.256128     -16.94
13    138       62     0.044497      1.242726     -16.44
14    139       63     0.040030      1.231342     -15.94
15    140       64     0.035721      1.217981     -15.44
16    141       65     0.034103      1.207120     -14.94
17    142       66     0.032650      1.198915     -14.44
18    143       67     0.029935      1.191560     -13.94
19    144       68     0.023893      1.191867     -13.44
20    145       69     0.023004      1.191797     -12.94
21    146       70     0.022116      1.191728     -12.44
22    147       71     0.021227      1.191658     -11.94
23    148       72     0.020338      1.191589     -11.44","[[0.00039583]
 [0.00041666]
 [0.        ]
 [0.00049999]
 [0.00054166]
 [0.00064582]
 [0.00118748]
 [0.00079165]
 [0.00149998]
 [0.        ]
 [0.00104165]
 [0.00114581]
 [0.00124998]
 [0.00133331]
 [0.00143748]
 [0.00154164]
 [0.00166664]
 [0.00174997]
 [0.00187497]
 [0.00197913]
 [0.0020833 ]
 [0.00222913]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]]"
1,29379.dat,"count           64.000000
EASTING (x)      0.137875
NORTHING (y)    -1.084750
depth          -23.000000
Name: 1, dtype: float64","    count  channel  EASTING (x)  NORTHING (y)  depth (m)
0     125       49     0.146875      1.391000     -22.94
1     126       50     0.140115      1.384478     -22.44
2     127       51     0.129401      1.372682     -21.94
3     128       52     0.118641      1.360286     -21.44
4     129       53     0.108410      1.348083     -20.94
5     130       54     0.099063      1.336708     -20.44
6     131       55     0.090169      1.324554     -19.94
7     132       56     0.080361      1.310292     -19.44
8     133       57     0.071939      1.297892     -18.94
9     134       58     0.065468      1.288199     -18.44
10    135       59     0.059845      1.278037     -17.94
11    136       60     0.054432      1.266832     -17.44
12    137       61     0.050194      1.256128     -16.94
13    138       62     0.044497      1.242726     -16.44
14    139       63     0.040030      1.231342     -15.94
15    140       64     0.035721      1.217981     -15.44
16    141       65     0.034103      1.207120     -14.94
17    142       66     0.032650      1.198915     -14.44
18    143       67     0.029935      1.191560     -13.94
19    144       68     0.023893      1.191867     -13.44
20    145       69     0.023004      1.191797     -12.94
21    146       70     0.022116      1.191728     -12.44
22    147       71     0.021227      1.191658     -11.94
23    148       72     0.020338      1.191589     -11.44","[[0.00039583]
 [0.00039583]
 [0.        ]
 [0.00045833]
 [0.00052082]
 [0.00060416]
 [0.00068749]
 [0.00072915]
 [0.        ]
 [0.00091665]
 [0.00099998]
 [0.00110415]
 [0.00120831]
 [0.00129165]
 [0.00139581]
 [0.00149998]
 [0.00160414]
 [0.00170831]
 [0.00181247]
 [0.0019583 ]
 [0.00193747]
 [0.00193747]
 [0.00193747]
 [0.00193747]]"
2,29380.dat,"count           65.000000
EASTING (x)      0.137875
NORTHING (y)    -1.084750
depth          -22.750000
Name: 2, dtype: float64","    count  channel  EASTING (x)  NORTHING (y)  depth (m)
0     125       49     0.146875      1.391000     -22.94
1     126       50     0.140115      1.384478     -22.44
2     127       51     0.129401      1.372682     -21.94
3     128       52     0.118641      1.360286     -21.44
4     129       53     0.108410      1.348083     -20.94
5     130       54     0.099063      1.336708     -20.44
6     131       55     0.090169      1.324554     -19.94
7     132       56     0.080361      1.310292     -19.44
8     133       57     0.071939      1.297892     -18.94
9     134       58     0.065468      1.288199     -18.44
10    135       59     0.059845      1.278037     -17.94
11    136       60     0.054432      1.266832     -17.44
12    137       61     0.050194      1.256128     -16.94
13    138       62     0.044497      1.242726     -16.44
14    139       63     0.040030      1.231342     -15.94
15    140       64     0.035721      1.217981     -15.44
16    141       65     0.034103      1.207120     -14.94
17    142       66     0.032650      1.198915     -14.44
18    143       67     0.029935      1.191560     -13.94
19    144       68     0.023893      1.191867     -13.44
20    145       69     0.023004      1.191797     -12.94
21    146       70     0.022116      1.191728     -12.44
22    147       71     0.021227      1.191658     -11.94
23    148       72     0.020338      1.191589     -11.44","[[0.00095832]
 [0.00095832]
 [0.        ]
 [0.00043749]
 [0.00049999]
 [0.00056249]
 [0.00064582]
 [0.00072915]
 [0.00081249]
 [0.00087499]
 [0.00095832]
 [0.00106248]
 [0.00116665]
 [0.00122915]
 [0.00122915]
 [0.00122915]
 [0.00122915]
 [0.00168747]
 [0.00122915]
 [0.00122915]
 [0.0020208 ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]]"
```

I build the `DataFrame` like so:

```
pickdf=pd.DataFrame({'filename':cc_file,'sourcedep':sd,'chanloc':chanloc,'picktime':cc_picks})
```

In the last column (picktime) the cells (each containing 24 values) could have a zero. I'd like to find those index values and use them to filter the matching rows in that column and column 3. That is, the lists in columns 3 and 4 are 24 rows long and I'd like to use the row indices from the zero values in column 4 to delete those rows and the corresponding rows in column 3.

I'm new to pandas and I think I'm almost there... I've tried using `df.explode('picktime').reset_index(drop=True)` to expand the last column and then using `df.loc[df['picktime'] != 0.]` to find and exclude the rows with zeros in column 4. I can't quite figure out how to use those same indices to remove the corresponding rows in column 3.

In the above sample of the dataframe I'd like to find the zeros in column 4 (picktime) (rows 1,4,5 and 22) and remove those rows from columns 3 and 4.

Comment: This isn't a good way to load each file. All this data is stored in each cell, which isn't how `pandas` works.  Please share one or two files and include the code used to load the data into `pandas`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Do you mean this isn't the correct way to create the `DataFrame`? I'm only using  `pandas`at the end of a long seismic data processing pipeline for a data container and for writing out a specifically formatted text file.

Comment: That's correct. What I'm seeing, if the sample correctly represents the real dataframe, is that each dataframe cell contains a lot of data. For example `df.iloc[0, 2]` is an entire table, in one cell. pandas is for tabular data, each cell should contain a single value.

Comment: The proper way to manage the pipeline is to probably load each file into a separate dataframe, and then confine the dataframes with `.concat`. Some other work will have to be done, for example the values in `picktime` should each be in a separate row corresponding to the rows of `'chanloc'`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney That is correct. Column 1 is a file name. Column 2 cells each contain a size(4,) array. Column 3 cells contain size (24,5) arrays and Column 4 cells contain size(24,1) arrays.  Can you recommend a better container to hold and manipulate this data?

Comment: `pandas` will work fine, but as mentioned, the data needs to be loaded properly. Currently, that is not the case.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I append to lists during processing and then add everything to one DataFrame at the end instead of appending a DataFrame inside of my loop.